# Storage for Chapter 2 in The Witcher 2

Tags: the-witcher-2

So I just got into chapter 2 for the most part, completed a couple missions. How do I get storage again like in chapter 1? I need to place stuff into storage to avoid being overweight and also get stuff from my storage to craft a better sword that I want.

Anyone know how to get the storage with everything in it again? I have unlocked the inn, to my knowledge anyway. I did the mission to save the guys son from being killed by the challenging man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what path you chose:

- If you followed **Roche's** path [Raymond Gessler](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Raymond_Gessler) in the [Camp followers' encampment](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Camp_followers%27_encampment)(south of Kaedweni Camp by the river) will provide you with storage.

[image]

- If you followed **Iorveth's** path there will be a chest in Geralt's room in [The Cauldron](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Cauldron)(Inn in Vergen).Not sure if storage can also be accessed by talking to innkeeper.

[image]

More info [here](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/The_Witcher_2_storage).Should be red due the possible bugs.

Comment: Awesome thanks a ton! I was starting to get annoyed with not having the storage. Any idea on how far through the chapter it is though?

Comment: I'm still not sure where exactly you are,but the storage should be available as soon as you can get there.

Comment: Hmm alright, I'll have to look into finding it then, I followed Roche so I have to go to the camp follower's encampment. I'm not positive where this is though, honestly have not the slightest where it is lol is it near the king's tent? the wiki doesn't show where it is specifically either.

Comment: King is in the Kaedweni camp,this is a bit south.Outside the walls near the river.Marked by number 12 on this map.
http://guides.gamepressure.com/thewitcher2assassinsofkings/guide.asp?ID=11424